# What is active record doing on the sql side in a polymorphic association?

Tags: sql, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I understand what is happening on the ruby level but when a model is represented as a foreign key on its own table, as in "a comment can have many comments" are new sql tables beign created to represent those comments under the hood? I apologize if my question is unclear. Any and all answers are much appreciated.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :content, {null: false}
      t.integer :commentable_id, {null: false}
      t.string :commentable_type, {null: false}
      t.references :commenter, null: false

      t.timestamps(null: false)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: There will be only one database table generated here, `comments`. What did you mean by "sql tables"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly in your migration you can use polymorphic: true to create the polymorphic references:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :content, {null: false}
      t.references :commentable, polymorphic: true, index: true
      t.references :commenter, null: false

      t.timestamps(null: false)
    end
  end
end
```

As you have already determined this will simply generate the `:commentable_id` and `:commentable_type` columns in your comments table that represent the polymorphic association - no special tables or other magic going on.

The `commentable_type` column is simply a string that stores the name of the model that the row `belongs_to`. The `commentable_id` is naturally an integer that holds the `id` of the model instance associated with this polymorphic association.

However, if you really want to find out whats going on under the hood just connect to your database and look at what you have.

Some useful commands to get you started (assuming you have connected to your database using psql) :

`\dt` (equivalent to SHOW TABLES)

`\d+ tablename` (equivalent to DESC tablename - where tablename is the name of the table you want information on)

Comment: Glad to be of help - if I have answered your question could you please up vote/accept :)

Answer (score 0):

Active Record uses the `commentable_type` column to `constantize` it and find the associated record by the `commentable_id`:

i.e.

```
commentable_type = "Post" # for example
commentable_type.constantize # returns the Post class model
commentable_type.constantize.find commentable_id # find the Post record

# the above line is equivalent to:
Post.find commentable_id
```